# parabola's directrix freedom extent

Tags: analytic-geometry

Directrix is equidistant from the focus of the parabola. Is it possible that the directrix can be placed anywhere in the cartesian plane and still make a legitimate parabola ? Or is there a limit for where the directrix to be placed to form a legitimate parabola in a cartesian plane. Thanks in advance

Comment: The directrix can be placed anywhere (the focus must not lie on the directrix).

Comment: Your first phrase is weird, and perhaps you meant: the parabola is the locus of all points which are quidistant from a point, called the parabola's focus, and a straight line called the directrix, *which does not pass through the focus*, so yes: given a point which will be the focus, to construct a directrix for a parabola you can choose *any* line not through that point.